# Cannot send email with amazon ses

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-ses

I am developing an Codeigniter based website and I need to send emails to people when they
are signup up. My server is hosted at Amazon EC2.

I am trying to use their Amazon Simple Email Service and I am using the below library to
get that working. I get no error but the sending fails. I am currently in Sandbox mode so I can only send (when it works) to my registered email address but that fails too.

I have configured the library using my AWS credentials. What can be wrong?

This is the library that I am using:

https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-amazon-ses

This is my controller code:

```
        // Load the Library

        $this->load->library('amazon_ses');

        // Configure and send email

        $this->amazon_ses->to('registered@email.com');
        $this->amazon_ses->subject('Open me!');
        $this->amazon_ses->message('<strong>Use HTML</strong>');

        if ($this->amazon_ses->send()) {

            echo "Successfully sent!";

        } else {

            echo "Failure!";

        }

        $this->amazon_ses->debug(TRUE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->amazon_ses->debug(TRUE);
```

That debug-line should be used before calling `...->send()`, try this and check what AmazonSES answers:

```
$this->load->library('amazon_ses');
$this->amazon_ses->to('registered@email.com');
$this->amazon_ses->subject('Open me!');
$this->amazon_ses->message('<strong>Use HTML</strong>');

$this->amazon_ses->debug(TRUE);
print_r( $this->amazon_ses->send() );
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the error: MissingAuthenticationToken. I have setup my AWS credentials in the config file. What can be missing?

Comment: @JonathanClark can you share what you did to cUrl?